# Meta Description tag including email

Tags: parsing, email, search, seo, meta

I'm a bit uncertain about the logistics of using an email address inside of a meta description tag.

I'd like to know if it's possible (I don't see why it couldn't be) or am I likely to run into an issue of a server not parsing the @ symbol?

Edit: removed additional question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having `bernard@example.com` (or `mailto:bernard@example.com`) in the `meta`-`description` is nothing different than having any other text there. User agents should interpret it as text, not as URI.

(Of course bots looking for email addresses might parse/understand it, but that’s obviously the case no matter where your publish the address. This question is not the appropriate place to discuss strategies to prevent bots from recognizing email addresses.)

In HTML5, unless the page is *about* this email address, it would probably be wrong to include it in the [`description`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/document-metadata.html#meta-description), as it (emphasis mine)

> […] must be a free-form string that **describes the page**.

(It should not describe the author, nor should it offer contact details.)

Comment: Thanks for the info, unor! My client is interested in having their email address show in the meta description for their contact page. I suppose it'd be one less click for a user to get in touch with them. I appreciate your assistance and will move forward accordingly.

Comment: @Bernard: On the contact page, it might make sense. However, they should keep in mind that those services which show the description (for example, search engines on their result pages) typically **a)** don’t make strings that look like URIs clickable (so users would have to copy/paste the address) and **b)** don’t necessarily show the full address (so users might copy a wrong/cut off address).